# Leaflet KML imported with Omnivore filled only with default blue and not the color set in KML file

Tags: polygon, leaflet, kml, leaflet-plugins

I have a KML file which I need to import in a map using Leaflet. If I use `leaflet-kml` I can see all polygons with color set from KML file.
But because I need to show only one polygon extracted for this file, in another question, someone suggests to use `leaflet-omnivore` which allow me to do that. In this way, for some reason, can't read the style in KML and use the blue for all polygons.

This is the map loaded with `leaflet-kml` with colors set by the KML file:

[image: Map with Leaflet-KML]

And the code with `leaflet-kml`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // Make basemap
        const key = 'xxx';
        const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);
        const gl = L.maplibreGL({
            style: `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/1cc7120b-9404-449d-8aca-dfcde7b44b89/style.json?key=${key}`
        }).addTo(map);

        map.attributionControl.setPrefix('');

            // Load kml file
            fetch('doc.kml')
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(kmltext => {
                    // Create new kml overlay
                    const parser = new DOMParser();
                    const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
                    const track = new L.KML(kml);
                    map.addLayer(track);

                    // Adjust map to show the kml
                    const bounds = track.getBounds();
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                });
    </script>
```

This is the map loaded with `leaflet-omnivore`:

[image: Map with Leaflet-Omnivore]

And the code with `leaflet-omnivore`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            // Make basemap
        const key = 'xxx';
        const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 1);
        const gl = L.maplibreGL({
            style: `https://api.maptiler.com/maps/1cc7120b-9404-449d-8aca-dfcde7b44b89/style.json?key=${key}`
        }).addTo(map);

        map.attributionControl.setPrefix('');

            // Load kml file
            var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
            // Filter desidered number
            //  filter: function(feature) {
            //    return(feature.properties.name == 'Territorio 050');
            //  },
              onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                if (feature.properties.name) {
                  layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
                }
              }
            });

            var kmlLayer = omnivore.kml('doc.kml', null, geoJsonLayer)
              .on('ready', function() {
                map.fitBounds(kmlLayer.getBounds());
              })
              .addTo(map);
    </script>
```

The KML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Nuova Mappa Residenziale</name>
    <description/>
    <Style id="poly-006064-1000-77-nodesc-highlight">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff646000</color>
        <width>1.5</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <color>4d646000</color>
        <fill>1</fill>
        <outline>1</outline>
      </PolyStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    ...
    <StyleMap id="poly-006064-1000-77-nodesc">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#poly-006064-1000-77-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#poly-006064-1000-77-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Folder>
      <name>Fucecchio Alto 001-014</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Territorio 001</name>
        <styleUrl>#poly-880E4F-1000-77-nodesc</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <tessellate>1</tessellate>
              <coordinates>
                10.80684,43.72934,0
                ...
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Territorio 002</name>
        <styleUrl>#poly-A52714-1000-77-nodesc</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <tessellate>1</tessellate>
              <coordinates>
                10.806808,43.734096,0
                ...
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Folder>
      <name>Fucecchio Nord 015-025</name>
      <Placemark>
        <name>Territorio 015</name>
        <styleUrl>#poly-FF5252-1000-77-nodesc</styleUrl>
        <Polygon>
          <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
              <tessellate>1</tessellate>
              <coordinates>
                10.801615,43.736216,0
                ...
              </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
          </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
      </Placemark>
```

Full KML file: https://pastebin.com/LuNLcArN

There is a way to read the color from file and show it like `leaflet-kml`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add relevant code of how you use both plugins. Also it would be helpful to get your whole KML file, if you can share it.

Comment: @TomazicM Thank you. Sorry if I made some mistakes. This is new for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to style features created by `leaflet-omnivore` plugin the same way as they are styled with `leaflet-kml` plugin is to take style analysis code from `leaflet-kml` plugin code and then apply styles with GeoJSON layer `style` option.

The following methods/functions have to be taken from `leaflet-kml` plugin: `parseStyles`, `parseStyle` and `parseStyleMap`. A piece of code dealing with icons has to be commented out in `parseStyle` function.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function parseStyles(xml) {
  var styles = {};
  var sl = xml.getElementsByTagName('Style');
  for (var i=0, len=sl.length; i<len; i++) {
    var style = this.parseStyle(sl[i]);
    if (style) {
      var styleName = '#' + style.id;
      styles[styleName] = style;
    }
  }
  return styles;
}

function parseStyle(xml) {
  var style = {}, poptions = {}, ioptions = {}, el, id;

  var attributes = {color: true, width: true, Icon: true, href: true, hotSpot: true};

  function _parse (xml) {
    var options = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
      var e = xml.childNodes[i];
      var key = e.tagName;
      if (!attributes[key]) { continue; }
      if (key === 'hotSpot')
      {
        for (var j = 0; j < e.attributes.length; j++) {
          options[e.attributes[j].name] = e.attributes[j].nodeValue;
        }
      } else {
        var value = e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        if (key === 'color') {
          options.opacity = parseInt(value.substring(0, 2), 16) / 255.0;
          options.color = '#' + value.substring(6, 8) + value.substring(4, 6) + value.substring(2, 4);
        } else if (key === 'width') {
          options.weight = value;
        } else if (key === 'Icon') {
          ioptions = _parse(e);
          if (ioptions.href) { options.href = ioptions.href; }
        } else if (key === 'href') {
          options.href = value;
        }
      }
    }
    return options;
  }

  el = xml.getElementsByTagName('LineStyle');
  if (el && el[0]) { style = _parse(el[0]); }
  el = xml.getElementsByTagName('PolyStyle');
  if (el && el[0]) { poptions = _parse(el[0]); }
  if (poptions.color) { style.fillColor = poptions.color; }
  if (poptions.opacity) { style.fillOpacity = poptions.opacity; }
  el = xml.getElementsByTagName('IconStyle');
  if (el && el[0]) { ioptions = _parse(el[0]); }
/*
  if (ioptions.href) {
    style.icon = new L.KMLIcon({
      iconUrl: ioptions.href,
      shadowUrl: null,
      anchorRef: {x: ioptions.x, y: ioptions.y},
      anchorType:   {x: ioptions.xunits, y: ioptions.yunits}
    });
  }
*/
  id = xml.getAttribute('id');
  if (id && style) {
    style.id = id;
  }

  return style;
}

function parseStyleMap(xml, existingStyles) {
  var sl = xml.getElementsByTagName('StyleMap');

  for (var i = 0; i < sl.length; i++) {
    var e = sl[i], el;
    var smKey, smStyleUrl;

    el = e.getElementsByTagName('key');
    if (el && el[0]) { smKey = el[0].textContent; }
    el = e.getElementsByTagName('styleUrl');
    if (el && el[0]) { smStyleUrl = el[0].textContent; }

    if (smKey === 'normal')
    {
      existingStyles['#' + e.getAttribute('id')] = existingStyles[smStyleUrl];
    }
  }
}

var styles;
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return(styles[feature.properties.styleUrl]);
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties.name) {
      layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
  }
});

var kmlFile = 'doc.kml';
fetch(kmlFile)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(kmltext => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
      styles = parseStyles(kml);
      parseStyleMap(kml, styles);
      var kmlLayer = omnivore.kml(kmlFile, null, geoJsonLayer)
        .on('ready', function() {
          map.fitBounds(kmlLayer.getBounds());
        })
        .addTo(map);
  });
```

As a result features are styled as with `leaflet-kml` plugin:

[image]

Here is working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/ktb63zew/

Comment: I have tried this code on mine but I can't get colors. Shows the polygon but blue. Can you post the code that work for you?

Comment: See edited answer with working JSFiddle.